# How secure would AES be with all round keys equal?

Tags: aes, key-schedule

In effect the same 128 bit key is XORed at every round and before and after as whitening.

Would it be 2^128?

What are the dangers of such a naive key schedule and does AES suffer from them?

Edit: Fair enough, slide attack is a problem. It doesn't explain however why there is a key schedule instead of round constants.

Comment: I believe it would be no better than AES with a single round (i.e. trivially breakable).

Comment: I believe it will be under slide attack , unless you add round constant

Comment: I've just added two other questions to the duplicate list, does this answer your updated question?